# Searching string from CSV one row at a time

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have Two CSV files, the first one is search item, and the other one is some sort of database. I want to implement a linear search between both files.

I'm using python 3.6

Here's my code:

```
import csv

macs = []
brands = []
macxs = []

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv:
            mac = row[0]
            brand = row[1]
            macs.append(mac)
            brands.append(brand)

def macslice(slice):
        return slice[:8]

with open('eggsample.csv') as csvfile2:
    readcsv2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    for row in readcsv2:
           macx = macslice(row[0])
           macxs.append(macx)

def compare():
        i=0
        while i < len(macs):
                if (macs[i] == macxs[i]):
                        print("FOUND", brands[i])
                        i += 1
                else:
                        print("NOT FOUND")
                        i += 1

def compare2():
        i=0
        while i < len(macxs):
                for x in macxs:
                        if (macs[i] == macxs[i]):
                                print("FOUND", brands[i]+" "+ macs[i])
                                i += 1
                        else:
                                print("BRAND not found for: ",macxs[i] )
                                i += 1

compare2()
```

Rather than doing a linear search, my code just compares the first line in first CSV with the first line in second CSV and so on until the end of both CSVs.

I expect some kind of linear search, line by line and return condition of line in first CSV.

Hope my description help my problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple dummy (maybe just 1 row for each files) of your sample that you are trying to compare?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your compare , as you are comparing with the indice `i`.

Rule of thumb, where are you using `x`in your compare2 ?

Switch to :

```
def compare2():

    for y in macs:
        for x in macxs:
                if x==y:
                    print("FOUND", x+" "+ y)

                else:
                    print("BRAND not found for: ",y )


compare2()
```

Or something similar.